# Reinstall Visual Studio 2017 extensions due to installation bug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Just upgraded to VS2017 15.3 (the latest version, released this week).

All my settings are gone. Also, all my extensions appear in the list, but they don't load. I uninstalled and installed one to see what would happen, and once I did that it started working again.

I can't spend a whole day doing that for dozens more. Is there a way to reinstall all the extensions in bulk?

---

*UPDATE*
Just upgraded to the bugfix release of yesterday, 15.3.1, and AGAIN, all my settings were lost, and again all my extensions were lost. VS buggy as always. There must be some way to prevent this sort of thing by reinstalling extensions in bulk! I spent the whole day reinstalling extensions, and reconfigurating the environment, and I saved my settings. Now I need to do it all again. Please advise if you've been through this as well and know of some trick to save time!!

Comment: `And as usual I'm gonna have to spend time fixing things.`  Is your question about bulk reinstallation or why you're having these issues? On my equipment, I've not had any bugs but maybe I'm using different/less extensions?

Comment: @Dave How to reinstall extensions, obviously. I'm no the only one, this is a problem that's been reported by others. But MS considers it fixed, even though it is not.